# Potential Optimised alternative linq query for finding non Existent records within a set of Ids

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, linq-to-entities

Let's say I have been given an array of Ids [integers] and I would like to know which one of them does not exist within a particular Db table [Table1 for instance]. Currently I use the following EF query [My version of EF is EF6 but I assume in this particular scenario using EF6 or EF Core would not matter]:

```
// Lets assume record with id = 9999 doesnt exist in the database 
IEnumerable<int> Ids = new [] { 1 ,2 ,3, 4, 9999}

var nonExistentIds = Ids.Except(myDbContext.Table1.Select(x => x.Id)
                                            .Intersect(Ids));
```

Above example will return [9999] which is the the record in the given array that doesn't exist in the database.

Could there be a potential better linq alternative [I am not looking for a native sql alternative] for discovering non existent records?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as `Ids` is reasonably small, I would use `Contains`:

```
var existingIds = myDbContext.Table1.Select(x => x.Id)
                                    .Where(id => Ids.Contains(id))
                                    .ToHashSet();

var nonExistentIds = ids.Where(id => !existingIds.Contains(id));
```

It should translate to something like

```
SELECT 
    [Extent1].[Id] AS [Id]
    FROM [dbo].[Table1] AS [Extent1]
    WHERE  [Extent1].[Id] IN (1, 2, 3, 4)
```

and then you reverse the result with LINQ to Objects.

You could also reverse with `Except`:

```
var nonExistentIds = ids.Except(myDbContext.Table1.Select(x => x.Id)
                                                  .Where(id => Ids.Contains(id)));
```

The benefit of `Contains` over `Intersect` is the way the list of ids is sent to SQL Server - `Intersect` constructs a table very verbosely, with `UNION ALL`, which more quickly overflows SQL.

Comment: Perhaps my question was not clear. I am trying to find the record within the given array that doesn't have a corresponding id inside the database table. Your answer is the other way around.

Comment: @MHOOS I did not get that from your set math, but reversing the `Contains` is still efficient, I think. The benefit of `Contains` over `Intersect` is the way the list of ids is sent to SQL Server - `Intersect` constructs a table very verbosely, with `UNION ALL`, which more quickly overflows SQL.

Comment: thanks for the answer and a question: you mentioned this in your answer:var nonExistentIds = ids.Where(id !=> existingIds.Contains(id)). Did you mean Where(id => !existingIds.Contains(id))? I have not seen !=> sign before?

Comment: @MHOOS I did - what I get for re-typing instead of cut/paste! Fixed.

Answer (score 0):

I would think the main alternative would be to use `.Distinct()` instead of `.Intersect(Ids)`. The former would return a larger list of numbers, while the later needs to send the list of IDs to the SQL server. I have no idea what would be faster, it is probably easiest to test.